# Display class containing a Canvas in a JFrame

Tags: java, swing, canvas

I've been using this class for so long, I never thought about how terribly big and how bad it looks. Looking back on it, this class looks so out-of-date, and nothing explains itself; I want to get it looking much better, not with all the extra junk that it doesn't need.
Here's the class:

```
import java.awt.Canvas;
import java.awt.Dimension;

import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Display {

    private JFrame frame;
    private Canvas canvas;

    private String title;
    private int width, height;

    public Display(String title, int width, int height){
        this.title = title;
        this.width = width;
        this.height = height;

        createDisplay();
    }

    private void createDisplay(){
        frame = new JFrame(title);
        frame.setSize(width, height);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setResizable(false);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);

        canvas = new Canvas();
        canvas.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(width, height));
        canvas.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(width, height));
        canvas.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(width, height));
        canvas.setFocusable(false);

        frame.add(canvas);
        frame.pack();
    }

    public Canvas getCanvas(){
        return canvas;
    }

    public JFrame getFrame(){
        return frame;
    }

}
```

Is there anything here I can condense, or any way to make it look cleaner?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

one minor issue - no redundant code...

```
canvas = new Canvas();
canvas.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(width, height));
canvas.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(width, height));
canvas.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(width, height));
canvas.setFocusable(false);
```

you should use

```
canvas.setPreferredSize(dim); //see below
canvas.setMaximumSize(dim);
canvas.setMinimumSize(dim);
```

that leads to another issue:
create a default constructor that doesn't require a size

```
private static final int DEFAULT_WIDTH = 100;
private static final int DEFAULT_HEIGHT = 100;
public Display(String title){
    this(title, DEFAULT_WIDTH, DEFAULT_HEIGHT);
}
```

and use this parametrized constructor:

```
//private int width, height; TODO remove: no more required
private static final Dimension dim;
public Display(String title, int width, int height){
    this.dim = new Dimension(width, height);
    createDisplay();
}
```

another issue would be removing unrequired attributes - whats the sense of keeping the title? just forward it...

```
//private String title; TODO remove: no more required
public Display(String title, int width, int height){
    this.dim = new Dimension(width, height);
    createDisplay(title);
}

private void createDisplay(final String title){
    frame = new JFrame(title);
    ...
}
```